# How to receive POST data in a PHP class

Tags: php

I have a class with contact form validation and a trait with a function which creates a token which is used for the validation.
I have tried to follow some advice from other stackoverflow posts but still can't figure out how to pass that token to the validation class. If I remove the token from the validation process it works fine.

My trait:

```
trait TokenTrait 
{
    public $token;

    function __construct () 
    {   
        if (!isset($token)) {
             return $this->token = bin2hex(random_bytes(64)); 
        }
    }
}
```

which is used in a class:

```
class Token 
{
    use TokenTrait;
}
```

Below a class with contact form validation. I have included only validation of the 'name' field for sake of simplicity. Also, I'm not including code for the function `test_input()` which is used here as it is irrelevant.

```
class ContactForm 
{
    use TokenTrait;

    public $name;
    public $name_error;
    public $token;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
        $this->name_error = isset($_POST['name_error']) ? $_POST['name_error'] : null;
        $this->token = isset($_POST['token']) ? $_POST['token'] : null;
    }

    function validateContactForm()
    {
        
        if (!empty($this->token)) {
            // Validate the token.
            if (hash_equals($_SESSION['token'], $_POST['token'])) {
                // If the token is valid proceed.
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        
                        // Rest of the validating code which works if I remove above token 
                        // or if I validate $_SESSION['token'] against itself.
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

And this is what i have in my view file:

```
$token_obj = new Token();
$token = $token_obj->token; // Variable used in a hidden input field in the contact `<form>` .

//The same token is stored in two different superglobals: POST and SESSION, which are validated against each other and if they don't match no message is not sent.
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;

// Declare variables used in the contact form.
$name = $email = $message = '';
$name_error = $email_error = $message_error = $result = '';

$contact_form_obj = new ContactForm();
$contact_form_obj->validateContactForm();
```

When I do `var_dump($contact_form_obj)`, `name` is NULL, `token` is NULL.

When I press `SUBMIT` in my contact form nothing happens bacuse `$_POST['token']` = NULL .

Comment: The constructor in the ContactForm-class overrides the constructor in your trait, so by using the trait there, all you're really doing is adding the property `token`, with no value. You even set that property in the ContactForm-class. I think you've confused yourself a lot here.

Comment: There's also some other issues here. 1. constructors can't return values. 2. you check `if (!isset($token)) {` (you probably menat `$this->token`?) is completely useless since it's in the constructor and there's no way it can have a value at this point.

Comment: Just put the code you have in your `TokenTrait` into your `Token`-class directly (with the changes I pointed out) and remove the trait completely. From what I can see, you don't need that trait (or the token class) in the ContactForm-class at all.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I did all you said and I'll keep it this way. I still can't get it to work, thought. It all worked nicely in flat PHP but I would like to take a step further and convert all my code into OOP.

Comment: Comments above are all good points. If you really want to reuse a constructor, maybe go with inheritance or move that functionality to a separate function that you could then call from the constructor of the other classes manually

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments pointed out, I think there are some problems with the approach that would likely rectify your issues. Try this:

```
trait TokenTrait 
{
    public $token = null;

    function setToken() 
    {   
        if ($this->token === null) {
            $this->token = bin2hex(random_bytes(64)); 
        }
        return $this->token;
    }
}

class Token 
{
    use TokenTrait;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setToken();
    }
}

class ContactForm 
{
    use TokenTrait;

    public $name;
    public $name_error;
    public $token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ?: null;
        $this->name_error = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name_error', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ?: null;
        $this->token = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'token', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW) ?: null;
    }

    public function validateContactForm()
    {
        if (!empty($this->token)) {
            // Validate the token. No need to pull from post since you did that in construct
            if (hash_equals($_SESSION['token'], $this->token)) {
                // If the token is valid proceed.
                if (getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
                    if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit') !== null) {
                        
                        // Rest of the validating code which works if I remove above token 
                        // or if I validate $_SESSION['token'] against itself.
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Granted, I can't see where all the pieces, such as your TokenTrait, fit into your larger Web App, but I'd question it's usefulness in the ContactForm class.

Comment: I also chose to use the `filter_input` method for retrieving variables. It's an extensive function with lots of options, but it gives you consistent results when it comes to return values (ie: null = not present, false = invalid) in addition to some handy out of the box methods for validating input. I also prefer `getenv()` to `$_SERVER` - really with exception to `$_SESSION` it's better to avoid tapping the `$_` globals directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the above. I removed the trait and put the token code directly in the class Token. I still can't get `validateContactForm()` to receive that token upon submitting the form, though.

Comment: You need to post your markup for the form then. If it's not there as a hidden input (or other) then that'd be your problem.

Comment: I'm using a hidden input in my form. It all works fine in flat PHP code. I can get it to work if I remove the class Token and its object and instead just use simple `$_SESSION['token']=bin2hex(random_bytes(64));` Maybe I just should do this instead of creating a class with the function setToken()? I have tried to declare $_SESSION['token'] as a public property in class Token but this seems not possible.

Comment: You could do something like `public function getToken() { return $_SESSION['token']; }` and that'd be fine. Not really sure why your code isn't working as is, but if making things simpler gets the job done, then maybe go that route. It might become more apparent to you later on. I suppose the only thing else I can think of is to make sure you are calling `session_start();` before you access `$_SESSION` regardless of how you end up using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the answer.

```
class Token 
{
    public $token;

    function __construct() 
    {   
        $this->token = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
    }
}


$token_obj = new Token();
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token_obj->token;
}
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
```

If you don't validate `$_SESSION['token']` first, it won't work.

Thank you guys for clarifying all this for me.